# Are immersions injective outside a set of measure zero?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-measure-theory

$\newcommand{\pl}{\partial}$
$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$

Let $\M,\N$ be smooth compact, connected, oriented manifolds of the same dimension.

Let $\,f:\M \to \N$ be a smooth immersion.

Does there exist a subset $A \subseteq \M$ of measure zero such that
$f|_{\M \setminus A}$ is injective?

Edit: As shown be the answer of Lee Mosher, the interesting case is when $\partial M \neq \emptyset$. For instance, $f:[0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{S}^1$, $f(t)=e^{it}$. (Then $A=\{ 0,2\pi\}$).

In the case where $\partial M \neq \emptyset$, $f$ is not an open map, so Lee's argument that $f$ needs to be injective does not stand as is.

Comment: I am confused. The only immersions I know in the stated context are covering maps, and I don't see how you could do what you ask for a nontrivial cover.

Comment: Example: $M=N=S^1$, $f(x) = 2x$ (or $x^2$ if you like multiplicative groups).

Comment: @MikeMiller $\mathcal{M}$ could be any open subset of a covering space of $\mathcal{N}$, for example.

Comment: @LeeMosher The OP demands his manifolds be compact. But perhaps boundary was desired and a closure of your suggestion works.

Comment: Oh, you are right.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, I meant to allow $\partial M \neq \emptyset$. How can we adapt Lee's argument to this case by "taking closure"?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Updated to take into account $\partial M \ne \emptyset$)

I'll write my answer using the Lebesgue measure class of a smooth volume form on $M$. The answer is that $A$ exists if and only if the restriction of $f$ to the manifold interior $\text{int}(M)$ is already injective, in which case you can take $A = \partial M$.

To prove this, suppose there exists $p \in \mathcal{N}$ and $x_1 \ne x_2 \in f^{-1}(p) \cap \text{int}(M)$. Then we may choose neighborhoods $U_1$ of $x_1$, $U_2$ of $x_2$, and $V$ of $p$, such that $f$ restricts to diffeomorphisms $U_1 \mapsto V$ and $U_2 \mapsto V$. Hence removal of a measure zero subset of $M$ leaves full measure subsets $A_1$ of $U_1$ and $A_2$ or $U_2$, each mapping to a full measure subset of $V$. The map $f$ is two-to-one over the full measure subset $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$ of $V$.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed meant to allow $\partial M \neq \emptyset$. Is there an adaptation of your approach that works in this case? ($f$ needs not be an open map then: Take $M=[0,1],N=[0,2],f(x)=x+1$).